# Would be possible to draw a sliding arrays window?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The diagram below look like a 3D diagram.

Would it be possible to draw in Latex?
I know it is unpolite to ask this question, but I really no idea how to start it even I was given the tutorial for TikZ.

I only able to draw:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
     
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0pt} % to reduce space above subcaption
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (6,6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{stuff}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: @AndréC. Actually, I only able to write one code. But I will edit my question again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the following code demonstrate all you need to complete your picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border = 0.5 cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1,-0.2)}, y={(0,0.8)}, z={(-0.5,-0.2)}] %adjust these numbers to get your preferred tilt and distance for everything
     \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
        \fill[green!30] (5,5) rectangle (8,8);
        \draw [gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (8,8); 
        \draw[red,thick] (6,6) rectangle (7,7);
        \fill[green,transparent] (5,5) rectangle (8,8);
     \end{scope}
     \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=6]
        \fill[green!30] (5,5) rectangle (8,8);
        \draw [gray,very thin] (5,5) grid (8,8);
        \draw[red,thick] (6,6) rectangle (7,7);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=10]
        \draw [gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (8,8); 
        \draw[red,thick] (6,6) rectangle (7,7);
    \end{scope}

\draw[blue,thick] (0,5,8) -- (10,5,8);
\draw[blue,thick] (0,8,5) -- (10,8,5);

\node at (0,6.5,6.5) {6};
\node at (6,6.5,6.5) {0};
\node at (10,6.5,6.5) {-3};
\draw[->] (0,9,9)node[above] {Source pixel} -- (0,7,6.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three tilted grids with numbers]

Comment: thanks. Brillant! I able to fill up the number in the box. However, any idea to add a label of each scope? For example just add in `Panel 1`, `Panel 2`, `Panel 3`.

Comment: I do not understand what "label of each scope" means!? Do you want the text `Panel 1` written above the left grid? Just do it the same way as the numbers.

Comment: @hperkristianse, thanks. sorry my mistake. Can i ask, how to make a acrow become ticker?

Comment: Search for "tikz arrow heads" and "tikz line width". Example: `\draw[-stealth,ultra thick] (0,9,9)node[above] {Source pixel} -- (0,7,6.5);`

Comment: thanks. I had selected your answer. I have another questions again https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558349/unable-to-find-a-grids-colour-it