# Unable to find a Grids / colour it

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I start with colour a grid box?
I want to draw below picture.

[image]

I had tried below.
It is very hard to guess the node number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
     
\begin{figure}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=0pt} % to reduce space above subcaption
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\node at (0,1,1) {6};
\node at (0,1,4) {6};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{stuff}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need TiKZ to do that. A simple tabular with \cellcolor is  enough.

Comment: @aan please see the answer for getting the grid coordinates on the grid itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean by "guess the node number". You are working in 2D here, so all coordinates should be given with only two numbers `(x,y)`. Here I start the 4 by 4 grid with lower left corner at `(0,0)` - all else follows naturally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\fill[yellow!20] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red!20] (0,2) rectangle (2,4);
%...
\draw[gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\node at (0.5,0.5) {1};
\node at (1.5,0.5) {2};
\node at (2.5,0.5) {3};
\node at (3.5,0.5) {4};
\node at (0.5,1.5) {3};
%...
\draw[-stealth,ultra thick] (5,2) --node[above] {max pool} (7,2);
\draw[gray,very thin] (8,1) grid (10,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Grid with a few numbers]

Comment: @hperkristiansen, thanks. How to fill the colour for the right hand side box? I couldn't figure out the meaning for `\fill[red!20] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);`

Comment: In this example, the right 2 by 2 grid has lower left corner at `(8,1)` and upper right corner at `(10,3)`. Try: `\fill[yellow!20] (8,1) rectangle (9,2);`

Comment: @hperkristiansen, thanks. Brillant! How to draw a circle like in the first diagram?

Comment: Search for "tikz circle". Example: `\draw (2,2) circle (3cm);`

Comment: @hperkristiansen, thanks. Yours is much better. I used this `\draw[] (-1.5,0.5) arc (10:300:-0.75cm)` and is weird. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The operative part of the grid coloring and putting data is as under --

```
{
\fill[yellow!20] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);%<----- the 0,0 corresponds to the coordinate 
                                               %system on the grid itself and 2,2 is 
                                               %the right upper corner of the 
                                               %rectangle 
%The green!20 says 20% green mixed with white color
%Bonus you can now create circles at any desired location also 
%Since each step is 1cm the circle radius as 1cm with red fill at coordinate 3,2

\fill[red!20] (3,2) circle (1cm);
\fill[green]     (-2,-2) rectangle (0,0);
\fill[blue!20]   (-2,0) rectangle (0,2);
\node at         (0.5,0.5) {1};
\node at         (-0.5,-0.5) {4};
}
```

The grid coordinates can now easily be read off from the grid itself with the excellent preamble created by  @AndrewStacey at  ---

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39698/197451

I think it was written to scare members!!

You could combine this with the excellent answer by  @hpekristiansen for connecting with the right hand grid

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, fit, matrix, positioning, shapes, backgrounds,}

\makeatletter
\def\grd@save@target#1{%
    \def\grd@target{#1}}
\def\grd@save@start#1{%
    \def\grd@start{#1}}
\tikzset{
    grid with coordinates/.style={
        to path={%
            \pgfextra{%
                \edef\grd@@target{(\tikztotarget)}%
                \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@target\grd@@target\relax
                \edef\grd@@start{(\tikztostart)}%
                \tikz@scan@one@point\grd@save@start\grd@@start\relax
                \draw[minor help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
                \draw[major help lines] (\tikztostart) grid (\tikztotarget);
                \grd@start
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xa}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@ya}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
                \grd@target
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xb}{\the\pgf@x/1cm}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yb}{\the\pgf@y/1cm}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@xc}{\grd@xa + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}}
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\grd@yc}{\grd@ya + \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}}
                \foreach \x in {\grd@xa,\grd@xc,...,\grd@xb}
                \node[anchor=north] at (\x,\grd@ya) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\x}};
                \foreach \y in {\grd@ya,\grd@yc,...,\grd@yb}
                \node[anchor=east] at (\grd@xa,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\y}};
            }
        }
    },
    minor help lines/.style={
        help lines,
        step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/minor step}
    },
    major help lines/.style={
        help lines,
        line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major line width},
        step=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/grid with coordinates/major step}
    },
    grid with coordinates/.cd,
    minor step/.initial=.2,
    major step/.initial=1,
    major line width/.initial=2pt,
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines,step=1cm] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
    \draw[help lines,line width=.6pt,step=1] (-2,-2) grid (7,4);
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
    \node[anchor=north] at (\x,-2) {\x};
    \foreach \y in {-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
    \node[anchor=east] at (-2,\y) {\y};
    \scoped[on background layer]
{
\fill[yellow!20] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[red!20] (3,2) circle (1cm);
\fill[green] (-2,-2) rectangle (0,0);
\fill[blue!20] (-2,0) rectangle (0,2);
\node at (0.5,0.5) {1};
\node at (-0.5,-0.5) {4};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%   
%   \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw (-2,-2) to[grid with coordinates] (7,4);
%   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `matrix` nodes instead of grids:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, arrows.meta}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={anchor=center, minimum size=8mm, fill=red!30, draw}] (LeftMatrix)
{1 & 1 &|[fill=green!30]| 2 &|[fill=green!30]| 4\\
5 & 6 &|[fill=green!30]| 7 &|[fill=green!30]| 8 \\
|[fill=yellow!30]|3 &|[fill=yellow!30]| 2 &|[fill=blue!30]| 1 &|[fill=blue!30]| 0 \\
|[fill=yellow!30]|1 &|[fill=yellow!30]| 2 &|[fill=blue!30]| 3 &|[fill=blue!30]| 4 \\};
 \draw[-{LaTeX}] ([xshift=2mm]LeftMatrix.east) -- node[above, align=left, font=\sffamily\small] {max pool with 2x2 filters\\ and stride 2} ++(0:4cm) coordinate(aux);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={anchor=center, minimum size=8mm, fill=red!30, draw}, right=5mm of aux] (RightMatrix)
{6 & |[fill=green!30]| 8\\
|[fill=yellow!30]| 3 & |[fill=blue!30]| 4 \\};
 
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]